# What does "to come from a place of (fear/insecurity/curiosity...)" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*for example :*

> **Musicians tend to come from a place of insecurity .**

this sentence gives me the sense of ***(having a past full of)*** insecurities.

> **John comes from a place of curiosity.**

in this case , it gives the sense that the ***(reason)*** for him to ask/do this is curiosity

> **it would be good to come from a place of wanting to share to help**

here i think it means **(to have the intention)** to help somebody

this is actually the best I could come up with.was i accurate enough? and are there any better ways to articulate the exact meaning of the sentences above ?

*some other contexts :*

> I want to continue being authentic. I want to come from a place
>   of truth, always.
>
> I would say sometimes wit can come from a place of thought
>
> To come from a place of compassion and understanding.
>
> Bullying tends to come from a place of low self-esteem

probably explaining these would be more challenging for me even though i believe i understand what they mean.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me put the exact meanings of the different cases into words.

Comment: "Hey man, where you coming from?" means "What's in your mind". But more generally, refers to someone's *background* or *history*, or the *origin* or *cause* of someone or something.

Comment: thank you that was helpful , maybe the word "background" is what I'm looking for.